# Correlation of linear combination of random variables

Tags: self-study, correlation

[image: Question]

How do I proceed further? (assuming what I did is correct in the first place)

Comment: Welcome to this site! You can use $\LaTeX$ to [format your post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/editing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables are a random sample - i.e. they are independent. Covariance of independent variables is zero, so you can eliminate $Cov(X_i, X_j)$ where $i\neq j$.

From the property of covariance, you obtain:
$Cov(U_m, U_n)=\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_i a_j Cov(X_i, X_j)= \sum_{i=1}^m a_i^2 Cov(X_i, X_i)=\sum_{i=1}^m a_i^2 \sigma^2$ (because $m \leq n$).

For correlation, lets calculate $Var(S_n), Var(S_m)$. Variance of sum of i.i.d. R.V.s equals to sum of their variances, hence $Var(S_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \sigma^2$, and similarly for $S_m$. Then:

$\rho(S_n, S_m)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m a_i^2 \sigma^2 }{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \sigma^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m a_i^2 \sigma^2}}$. It can be seen that if $m=n$, then correlation is 1.

If $a_i=\frac{1}{n}$, then $Cov(U_m, U_n)=\frac{m}{n^2}\sigma^2$ and correlation is $\frac{m}{\sqrt{mn}}$.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure of the independence but now it makes sense because they are a random sample :)